# Visualizing transitive reduction of the Hasse Diagram of the integer subset lattice

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a list of sets of integers, forming semi-lattice under inclusion relation. I need to visualize transitive reduction of the semi-lattice's Hasse Diagram. What is a good way to do this in Mathematica?

For instance, take these sets

```
sets = {Range[0, 5], Range[1, 2], Range[2, 3], Range[1, 2], 
  Range[3, 5]}
```

The graph should look something like this, minus the dashed lines (those are edge that get removed by transitive reduction)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sets = {Range[0, 5], Range[3], Range[1, 2], Range[2, 3], Range[1, 2],  Range[3, 5]};


vSF = Inset[Framed[NumberLinePlot[Interval[MinMax @ #2], 
 PlotRange -> {MinMax@sets, All}, Spacings -> 0, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Orange, CapForm["Round"]], 
 Ticks -> {Range @@ MinMax@sets}], RoundingRadius -> 5], #] &;


TransitiveReductionGraph[
 RelationGraph[UnsameQ[##] && SubsetQ[#2, #] &, sets], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful, thanks!